# Linux mint partition problem

Tags: linux-mint

When i started working with linux mint this partition was working well then mounting error began to appear and i solved it doing:

```
sudo ntfsfix dev/sda
```

mounting error came many times, but this time after solving mounting error  using this code another error came says:

(Sorry, could not display all the contents of "partition name": Error when getting information for file '(partition location)/found.000': Input/output error)

Note:
I have windows os too, in the same computer, and I don't use a virtual machine. And I checked that partition in windows and it works well.[image: error image]

Comment: Use only the NTFS partition for reading. The writing functionality from Linux is not entirely stable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 10, it has a Fast Startup feature that essentially hibernates the OS instead of really shutting down. As a result, NTFS filesystems are left in open state, which makes them unmountable in Linux, unless you first use `ntfsfix`.

On dual-boot systems, it is probably best to disable Windows Fast Startup if you want to access the NTFS filesystems from the Linux side.

---

```
sudo ntfsfix dev/sda
```

I'm guessing this is not an exact representation of the command you used.
Running `ntfsfix` on the whole `/dev/sda` disk instead of just the NTFS partition (e.g. `/dev/sdaN` where N is a number) is not advisable and might cause filesystem corruption issues.

Comment: i disabled Windows Fast Startup but nothing change